# Why is O(2^n) different from O(2^(n/2))?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Consider the following problem from a book which is trying to explain the "meet in the middle" technique - https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf (page 54, PDF p64)

> As an example, consider a problem where we are given a list of n numbers and a number x, and we want to find out if it is possible to choose some numbers from the list so that their sum is x. For example, given the list [2,4,5,9] and x = 15, we can choose the numbers [2,4,9] to get 2+4+9 = 15. However, if x = 10 for the same list, it is not possible to form the sum.
>
> ...
>
> A simple algorithm to the problem is to go through all subsets of the elements and check if the sum of any of the subsets is x. The running time of such an algorithm is O(2<sup>n</sup>), because there are 2<sup>n</sup> subsets. However, using the meet in the middle technique, we can achieve a more efficient O(2<sup>n/2</sup>) time algorithm. Note that O(2<sup>n</sup>) and O(2<sup>n/2</sup>) are different complexities because 2<sup>n/2</sup> equals √2^n.

1. They're square rooting the Big Oh time by splitting the subset. But exactly why is that different from the original 2<sup>n</sup> anyway?
2. Say that those two times are different. Is the difference really that significant?
3. Instead of just halving the set, why don't they go down recursively to the base case where you only have one element sets and 2^1 subsets (like in merge sort)? Wouldn't that make the efficiency better if you added those together?

PS: I know this book is a bad C++ reference, but I'm using it moreso for algorithm explanations.

Comment: Is the difference significant? Imagine n is 20. One is 1048576, the other 1024. That’s 1024x difference already. Now imagine n is 100, or 1000, or 1000000...

Comment: _"But exactly why is that different "_ apply the definition of asymptotic complexity and see for yourself.

Comment: I have never heard the term "asymptotic complexity" before. Is there someplace it is explained properly?

Comment: It does explain it, `because 2n/2 equals √2^n.` And `Sqrt(N)` and `N` are different complexities, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that they would be the same. Then you could say that *2<sup>n</sup> = O(2<sup>n / 2</sup>)*. That means that there is some *c > 0* and an *n'* such that for all  *n > n'*,

*2<sup>n</sup> < c 2<sup>n / 2</sup>*.

By dividing both sides, this is equivalent to saying that, for all  *n > n'*,

*2<sup>n / 2</sup> < c* .

This is obviously impossible, since the left side goes to infinity with large enough *n*, so it is not bounded by any *c*.

Comment: Nice answer, this also explains why `O(N/2)` is the same as `O(N)`, as there is `c = 2` that makes `O(c * N/2) = O(N)`.